Sitecore intranet not displaying images 403 no access
I’m working on a project where we need to set up preview sites for business managers to review content before publication. These preview sites require users to be signed in with their Azure AD accounts, and we’ve configured these sites as intranets by setting login to true in the site definitions and pointing the site to the master database.
While the setup works smoothly overall, we’re encountering an issue with displaying images on the preview sites. After a user with the reviewer role logs in, the site loads, but images hosted by Sitecore are being redirected (302) to a default “no access” page that returns an Access Denied (403) error.
Here’s a breakdown of the issue:
We’ve set up four Azure AD groups, each mapped to a specific user role:

Admin: Images load correctly.
Super Editor: Images do not load.
Basic Editor: Images do not load.
Reviewer: Images do not load.

Since the admin user can load images, this rules out folder or firewall permission issues. The problem seems to be related to Sitecore's application layer.
I’ve verified in Sitecore that the users have access to the media library using the Access Viewer and have full read permissions. The Basic Editor can publish and edit content without issues, which indicates they have media access within Sitecore.
Despite my efforts to find similar issues, I haven’t come across anything quite like this. What could be causing the three non-admin users to be blocked from accessing media?

This is happening because of the logic inside DoProcessRequest method for the media request handler.
Inside this handler, there is a logic to set the media using Security Disabler, when media is returned null. Once this happens, it redirects to No Access Page.

You can modify this logic by creating custom media request handler extending OOTB Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaRequestHandler, to handle the issue you are facing by specifying handler on Web.config as below.
<handlers>
      <add verb="*" path="sitecore_media.ashx" type="{{Custom_MediaRequestHandler}}" name="Sitecore.MediaRequestHandler" />
</handler>

Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have any doubts.
